# create symbol or rename a function inside WinDBG

Tags: debugging, windbg, ida, ollydbg, x64dbg

is there a way to rename a function in  windbg? similar of using symbol.

For example, we have a function that is identified in windbg as "example+0x14". after reverse engineering, I know this function is making call to a trampoline that will do printf. Now, I want to rename the "example+0x14" to "example-printf".

Doing this is very straightforward in other debuggers like (x64), but I couldn't find a way of doing this in windbg.

eventually, I want to resolve the addresses in the IAT, find their references (trampolines), rename those trampolines and make my debugging easier.

is there a way of doing it?

Comment: you can check this repo of mine for a sample AddSyntheticsymbol extension https://github.com/blabberer/windbg_labeller

Answer (score 2):

There is an API with which you can do this.  Unfortunately, there isn't a "command" to do it.  One could be created very easily from a debugger extension.

The API in question is **IDebugSymbols3::AddSyntheticSymbol** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugsymbols3-addsyntheticsymbol) or the Unicode variant **IDebugSymbols3::AddSyntheticSymbolWide** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugsymbols3-addsyntheticsymbolwide).

You can go **much further** than this if you want to write a plug-in.  There are new target composition APIs to the debugger (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Debugging.TargetModel.SDK) which allow you to define your own notion of what symbols are by providing a symbol provider (**DEBUG_SERVICE_SYMBOL_PROVIDER / ISvcSymbolProvider**).  The only sample (https://github.com/microsoft/WinDbg-Samples/tree/master/TargetComposition/TextDump) currently available for that API surface unfortunately does not yet cover symbols.  In the near future (hopefully within a month or two), there will be a second sample in that same repo which will cover this and allow a whole lot of dynamic manipulation and editing of symbols **AND** type system.

JFYI: in regard to your comments about the IAT.  The *ImageInfo.js* JavaScript extension which is included with the debugger already parses the IAT and exposes much of that information through the data model.  Everything it exposes is on the **Contents** property of a module object.  The IAT information is within **.Contents.Imports**:

```
0:007> dx -r3 @$curprocess.Modules[0].Contents.Imports
@$curprocess.Modules[0].Contents.Imports                
    ["KERNEL32.dll"] : KERNEL32.dll
        ModuleName       : KERNEL32.dll
        ResolvedModule   : C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
            BaseAddress      : 0x7ff8eef70000
            Name             : C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
            Size             : 0xbd000
            Contents        
            ImageType        : PE
        Functions       
            [0x0]            : Named Import of 'SetEvent'
            [0x1]            : Named Import of 'GlobalFree'
            [0x2]            : Named Import of 'GetLocaleInfoW'
            [0x3]            : Named Import of 'CreateFileW'
            [0x4]            : Named Import of 'ReadFile'
            ...
    ["GDI32.dll"]    : GDI32.dll
        ModuleName       : GDI32.dll
        ResolvedModule   : C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
            BaseAddress      : 0x7ff8f0750000
            Name             : C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
            Size             : 0x29000
            Contents        
            ImageType        : PE
        Functions       
            [0x0]            : Named Import of 'CreateDCW'
            [0x1]            : Named Import of 'StartPage'
            [0x2]            : Named Import of 'StartDocW'
            [0x3]            : Named Import of 'SetAbortProc'
            [0x4]            : Named Import of 'EndDoc'
            ...
```